# which directory to be in when installing programs

Tags: software-installation, directory, raspberry-pi

Does it matter in which directory I'm "sitting" in when I install a package on a Raspberry Pi? For instance, I want to install GIT and have it accessible everywhere. When I log into the Pi, I'm sitting in the Pi user's home directory. If I install using `sudo apt install git` will GIT be accessible anywhere? I ask because sometimes I'll install something like Docker and if I run `docker --version` it will tell me the version but if I try to run an sh file it says it can't find docker. I assume this is because I installed something to the wrong place. thanks

Comment: It does not matter where you are.

Comment: Your problem with `docker` might also arise from the docker binary not being found in your `PATH` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter what directory you are in to install programs. The problem with using docker is probably you did not install it correctly, i am assuming you did not start it with your init system.

If you are using systemd try:

```
sudo systemctl start docker

sudo systemctl enable docker
```

If this doesn't work try looking at this site here https://www.linux.com/topic/desktop/how-install-and-use-docker-linux/

Comment: that was it, thank you